# Automatic calling all the functionality of a component from another component in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a two components. One is student component and the other is result component. In student component, there is a modal that is showing the student's information and I want to open that modal from the result component and automatically call all the functionalities of student component from the result component.
Note: there are a lot of functions that I want to be called automatically from the result component by just opening the modal.

Comment: Hi Nouman, Welcome to Stack overflow. Have you ever seen this page? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You can use `@Input`, `BehaviorSubject` or `@EventEmitter` to achieve this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have `Student` component and `Result` component.
Inside `Student` Component, you have a `Result` modal that needs to be opened.

What's not clear is, is the `Result` modal being shown from the `Result` or the `Student` component?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *call all the functionalities*? If these are some functions that you want to call, you can define functions for those and then call them from `ngOnInit` of the Student Component. As soon as the StudentComponent is initialized, `ngOnInit` will get called which internally will call all these functions.

Comment: Let me give you an example:  in students component i can view the student information in a modal. but if there is a notification of that student in the navbar and when i click on that notification, it should open up that student information modal and the user can edit and delete the student

Comment: @NoumanMukhtar have you some code to show us? I can make you a generic example tho without any code to show you how the logic works.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for your quick response. I have solved my issue by Inheritance i.e by extending the student class from the result class